# How to create notification bar sliding like notification bar on Jelly Bean?

Tags: android, user-interface, slider

I wanna create notification bar sliding like notification bar on Jelly Bean.
I tried to implement from [umanno](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) but the animation when second view come not like i want.